# assembly code to add two integers

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have trouble understanding the following assembly code which is used to add two integers using registers. It's not a very cumbersome question, just that I lack any good reference to learn the syntax. If you can provide me with the insight line by line. I would be extremely grateful.

```
MOV R1, #100
MOV R2, #100
MOV (R1), #50
ADD R2,(R1)
```

I get the first two lines which will store number 100 in the given registers, I just don't get the purpose of using brackets in next two lines.
And this is not homework, Just a question to clarify the theory behind it.

Question is what are the values of R1, R2 after the instructions have been executed.

Comment: What do *you* think the answers are, and why? We're not here to do your homework (after all, we don't get the credit)

Comment: Actually, @Damien_The_Unbeliever academic honesty would require that SO be given credit. Otherwise it would be plagiarism, which most schools consider a serious offense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: This is not a homework question, And I'm not a college student, I'm self studying ISA. I didn't ask for the answer just the theory behind using brackets in the instruction.( v.putha)

Comment: Square brackets and parentheses are a common assembly language conventions to indicate that a value is used as a memory address. So the example code would "move" the value 100 to R1, move the value 100 to R2, move the value 50 to the memory address in R1--i.e., 100--, and add the value in the memory address referenced by R1--to which was just stored the value 50--to the value in R2 (with the result being placed in R2).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Thanks sir, that pretty much clarified the use of brackets for me. Much Obligated. :)

Comment: @chamara I guess another thing worth mentioning here is that given Paul Clayton's response, you are assuming a register-memory architecture, which is the one that allows you to perform operations on operands one of which is in memory and the other in a register. Here's more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_memory_architecture

Answer (score -1):

I found the following explanation on another website, which helped me a lot to understand the use of brackets. I believe it would be very clarifying for other people too, so I will post it below:

---

Lets analyze this program:

MOV AX, 47104
MOV DS, AX
MOV [3998], 36
INT 32

... The first instruction, MOV AX, 47104, tells the computer to copy the number 47104 into the location AX. The next instruction, MOV DS, AX, tells the computer to copy the number in AX into the location DS. The next instruction, MOV [3998], 36 tells the computer to put the number 36 into memory location 3998. Finally, INT 32 exits the program by returning to the operating system.

Before we go on, I would like to explain just how this program works. Inside the CPU are a number of locations, called registers, which can store a number. Some registers, such as AX, are general purpose, and don't do anything special. Other registers, such as DS, control the way the CPU works.

DS just happens to be a segment register, and is used to pick which area of memory the CPU can write to. In our program, we put the number 47104 into DS, which tells the CPU to access the memory on the video card.

The next thing our program does is to put the number 36 into location 3998 of the video card's memory. Since 36 is the code for the dollar sign, and 3998 is the memory location of the bottom right hand corner of the screen, a dollar sign shows up on the screen a few microseconds later.

Finally, our program tells the CPU to perform what is called an interrupt. An interrupt is used to stop one program and execute another in its place. In our case, we want interrupt 32, which ends our program and goes back to MS-DOS, or whatever other program was used to start our program.

---

We can see from this example that the use of brackets resulted in inputting a value into a memory location, and not into a register. Lately, this value was read by the video card to display a symbol on the screen.

Credits to the writer on: http://www.swansontec.com/sprogram.html